# Small File Upload with Flask is Slow

Tags: javascript, flask, file-upload, filereader

I'm uploading small files (sub 20k) using Fetch and Flask, however it can take up to 10 seconds to post, process and then return. Conversely, if i run the same functions in pure python only the same load and process time is less than a second.

When running a file upload with no processing it is almost instant upload.

Am I missing something that slows things down when Im processing files in with Flask?

I've tried uploading with no processing (fast), I've tried processsing with no flask (fast). I've tried uplaoding and processing from browser with flask(slow)

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, jsonify, Response, Flask, session, make_response, Markup
import io, random, sys, os, pandas

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route("/")

############################################################
@app.route("/routee", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def routee():

    return render_template('Upload Test.html')
############################################################
@app.route("/routee/appendroute", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def appendroute():
    PrintFlask(request.files.getlist('route'))

    return make_response(jsonify('Voyage = VoyageJson, Intersects = IntersectJson'), 200)
############################################################

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function prepformdata(route){
  formdata = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < route.files.length; i++) {
    formdata.append('route', route.files[i]);
  }
  return formdata
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function appendroutes(formdata, route) {

    uploadfiles = document.getElementById("files")

    formdata = prepformdata(uploadfiles)
    InitConst ={method: "POST",body: formdata} 
    url = window.origin + '/routee/appendroute'
    fetch(url,InitConst)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {addon = data['Voyage']; addonIntersects = data['Intersects']})
    .then(() => console.log('Route(s) Added'))
}
</script>

Whilst the code above is very nippy. I'm expecting to do some equally nippy processing server side. But something is slowing it down. Any ideas why processing might slow down when flask is used?
```

Comment: Have you omitted the processing steps? It's not clear what the processing is on the server side, and it seems that this is where the issue is based on your description - if possible please can you show the processing code in the flask app?